# Integrating the delta function

Tags: integration

So i was trying to figure out how the delta function is integrated and i got lost trying to figure out how they reached the last step, i tried integration by parts but got stuck

$$d_K(x)\equiv\int_{-\frac {K}2}^{\frac K2}{\frac {dk}{2\pi}}e^{ikx}={\frac{1}{\pi x}}\sin{\frac {Kx} 2}$$

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx\,d_K(x)={\frac 2 \pi}\int_0 ^{\infty}{\frac {dx} x}\sin{\frac{Kx}2}={\frac{2}\pi}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{dy} y}\sin y=1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi x}\sin(\frac{Kx}{2})dx=\frac{K}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{Kx}{2})}{\frac{Kx}{2}}dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

by the Dirichlet integral.